# Create object by drag and drop at runtime in unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I have to create object by dragging the button at run time. I have searched a lot but still I can't find solution.

I am creating object by clicking the button by using following sample code. but I have to drag and drop.

My code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CreateSphere : MonoBehaviour {

public void OnClick()
{
    GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Sphere);
    sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(3.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f) ;
    //transform.Translate(0, 0, Time.deltaTime);
    sphere.transform.position = new Vector3 (4, 0, 0);

}
}
```

Comment: You need a way to track the mouse position in the world and continually update the new `GameObject`'s position to match, until you let go of the mouse. Things like `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` and `Input.mousePosition` will help.

Answer (score 0):

`OnClick` is not dragging, its just a click. To drag you need to have drag handlers

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.GUI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class CreateSphere : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler {

    GameObject sphere;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
        // Begin dragging logic goes here

        sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Sphere);
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
        // Dragging logic goes here

        sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(3.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f) ;
        //transform.Translate(0, 0, Time.deltaTime);
        sphere.transform.position = new Vector3 (4, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i drag the button little bit the object is created at point 0,0,0. but i have to create object where i release the mouse button(on drop).How to do that?

Comment: Implement the `IEndDragHandler` interface and then use the method `public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData data) {}` for that logic